# Will Apple reject Mac OS App which uses IOKit framework?

Tags: cocoa

Will Apple reject Mac OS App which uses IOKit framework to read something like CPU temperature?

I found the online reference here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000815, so it is safe to use these list headers, right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your app will not be rejected because due to use of `IOKit`.
I actually have an app on the Mac App store that uses `IOKit` and it was approved with no issues.

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, the Mac App Store sample authorization code uses IOKit, does it not? I know NPReceiptVerification (commonly used) uses it.

Answer (score 3):

The app will not be rejected because you use a valid Framework provided by Apple ;)

I found an [App Store Pre-Submission Test](http://www.makayama.com/checklist.html) for you.